# retornar mensagem ao usuário

Tags: php

Como posso trocar a mensagem de "Faça o seu login" para "Bem Vindo, Usuário X". Na página index.html.

na index. html está assim

```
<p class="login"><b><a href="login.php">Faça o seu login!</a></b></p>
```

após os dados digitados são passados para a valida

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="valida.php">
```

e na valida esta assim se caso o login der certo :

```
if(isset($resultado)){
            $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
            $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
            //$_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
            $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email'];
                        if($_SESSION['usuarioId'] == $resultado['id']){
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inicialmente o seu index deverá ser .php para conseguir fazer a mudança que irei dar como exemplo. 
No index você coloca um if para verificar se existe uma session caso existir mostra uma div caso contrario mostra a de login. Exemplo:

index.php

```
if (isset($_SESSION['usuarioNome'])) {
   echo '<p class="exemplo"><b><a href="">Bem Vindo, Usuário '.$_SESSION['usuarioNome'].'</a></b></p>';
}
else{
   echo '<p class="login"><b><a href="login.php">Faça o seu login!</a></b></p>';
}
```

Comment: ainda não consegui exibir a mensagens de boas vindas apenas volta para o index, salvei como index.php e coloquei o código:

Comment: <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['usuarioNome'])) {
   echo '<p class="exemplo"><b><a href="">Bem Vindo, Usuário '.$_SESSION['usuarioNome'].'</a></b></p>';
}
else{
   echo '<p class="login"><b><a href="login.php">Faça o seu login!</a></b></p>';
}

?>

Comment: já tem o session_start() no seu projeto?

Comment: não vou testar agora com o session_start();

Comment: coloca ele antes da seguinte linha-> $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];

Comment: Muito obrigada, deu certo esse código que você me passou. Eu testei aqui, primeiro faço o meu login, depois aparece o nome do usuario que eu loguei apenas. Deus te abençoe pela ajuda!

Comment: De nada. Por gentileza marque a resposta como aceita.

Comment: Vale ressaltar que o `session_start();` deve estar antes de qualquer saída do php para o navegador (geralmente nas primeiras do arquivo logo após a tag `<?php`) para evitar o erro `Headers already sent`